# Convert a symbol to bitmap in Flash using Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing a small game using Flash CC. The question may seem very absurd since I am a novice to coding and Action Script.

Here it goes: Can we write a code to convert a symbol to bitmap?

Actually, the game has multiple objects and I have defined them as buttons. When the user clicks on one of the object, it moves to a new position. I dont want two objects simultaneously to move to a new position.

My logic: If I can make every other object as a bitmap, the user wont be able to click on any other object when one object is moving. Any thoughts???

Comment: What you are speaking about ?! You don't need to convert your objects to bitmaps because it's impossible that two objects get clicked in the same time ! Show us your code and how did you used your mouse events listeners.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible.

this code makes a bitmap from your displayObject:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(symbol.getBounds(this).width,symbol.getBounds(this).height,true);
//The BitmapData Class contains pixels information for a bitmap.I created a bitmap data  
//with width and height of the symbol. and set visiblity true.
var bitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bitmapData);
//you know about this !

bitmapData.draw(symbol);
//The draw() method, does what you want.set pixels from a DisplayObject 
//and use a matrix in parameters for the rotated,scaled,... form of the DisplayObject.
```

Now, The bitmap is ready.

I h☺p e  this helps !

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The code makes sense, though it didnt work as I had intended to. It would be great if you could break down the syntax of this code for me.

Comment: 1.never forget to `addChild(bitmap)`;2.I added explaination to the code.